# .NET & SQL database - recording stats

Tags: sql, statistics, analytics

Has anyone got any suggestions on the best way to code the following.
I am currently working on a banner advert section that needs to record the impressions and clicks of each banner.

I can write a row to a database table each time the image is loaded (or clicked) however I am concerned when I need to make the backend analytics to filter on day/month/year for the banner it is going to be slow.

For example if i have 1,000000 rows with a banner ID and a datetime that I need to filter on.

Also concerned about writing to the DB all the time from the frontend. If a page has 5 banners that's 5 new rows added per view of the page per visit.

Any ideas 
Thanks

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: Personally, I think the database engine is irrelevent in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a collection table and a query table.  The collection table would not have any indexes to slow down the insertion of records.  The query table would have indexes to speed up queries.

At the interval of your choice copy the records from the collection table to the query table, then empty the collection table.

Don't worry about a million rows.  A good database engine can handle it.

Comment: Depends on how many millions, and its not just how good the database engine is.

Comment: Most databases should be able to deal with 500m-1bn fairly easily @EkoostikMartin, especially if the table is as thin as the OP indicates.